# Vaadin Warning: widgetset version 6.7.2 does not seem to match theme version

Tags: vaadin

I've been developing on 6.7.2 for quite some time and yesterday I noticed the weird looking version of my application. I went to the debug version and found this:

```
Starting Vaadin client side engine. Widgetset: Xinco
Widget set is built on version: 6.7.2
Warning: widgetset version 6.7.2 does not seem to match theme version
Starting application xincovaadin-1652339780
Vaadin application servlet version: 6.7.2
Application version: NONVERSIONED
inserting load indicator
Making UIDL Request with params: init
Server visit took 30ms
JSON parsing took 0ms
Assuming CSS loading is not complete, postponing render phase. (.v-loading-indicator height == 0)
```

How can I fix this? I tried rebuilding my widgets without luck. Line 11 above repeats lots of times.

See: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/953384

**Edit:**

From Firebug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
<link href="/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="icon">
<title>Xinco</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8084/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/easyuploads.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8084/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/expandingtextarea/expandingtextarea.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8084/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/stepper/stepper.css">
</head>
<body class="v-generated-body v-ff v-ff8 v-ff80 v-gecko v-win" scroll="auto">
<script type="text/javascript">
<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" src="javascript:false" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;overflow:hidden;" tabindex="-1">
<script src="/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/Xinco.nocache.js?1323124855776" language="javascript">
<script src="http://localhost:8084/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/swfupload.js" language="javascript">
<script defer="defer">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="xincovaadin-1652339780" class="v-app v-theme-xinco v-app-Xinco">
<noscript>You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.</noscript>
<iframe id="Xinco" src="javascript:''" style="position: absolute; width: 0pt; height: 0pt; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1">
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I see when looking at the page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<style type="text/css">html, body {height:100%;margin:0;}</style><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/favicon.ico" /><link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/favicon.ico" /><title>Xinco</title>
</head>
<body scroll="auto" class="v-generated-body">
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(!vaadin || !vaadin.vaadinConfigurations) {
 if(!vaadin) { var vaadin = {}} 
vaadin.vaadinConfigurations = {};
if (!vaadin.themesLoaded) { vaadin.themesLoaded = {}; }
vaadin.debug = true;
document.write('<iframe tabIndex="-1" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;overflow:hidden;" src="javascript:false"></iframe>');
document.write("<script language='javascript' src='/xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/Xinco.nocache.js?1323183529006'><\/script>");
}
vaadin.vaadinConfigurations["xincovaadin-1652339780"] = {appUri:'/xinco/vaadin', standalone: true, themeUri:"/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco", versionInfo : {vaadinVersion:"6.7.2",applicationVersion:"NONVERSIONED"},"comErrMsg": {"caption":"Communication problem","message" : "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.","url" : null},"authErrMsg": {"caption":"Authentication problem","message" : "Take note of any unsaved data, and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.","url" : null}};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if(!vaadin.themesLoaded['xinco']) {
var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
stylesheet.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
stylesheet.setAttribute('href', '/xinco/VAADIN/themes/xinco/styles.css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
vaadin.themesLoaded['xinco'] = true;
}
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
setTimeout('if (typeof Xinco == "undefined") {alert("Failed to load the widgetset: /xinco/VAADIN/widgetsets/Xinco/Xinco.nocache.js?1323183529006")};',15000);
//]]>
</script>
<div id="xincovaadin-1652339780" class="v-app v-theme-xinco v-app-Xinco" ><div class="v-app-loading"></div></div>
<noscript>You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.</noscript></body>
</html>
```

The source code can be downloaded from [here](https://xinco.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/xinco). The project is a NetBeans project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which theme are you using? Assuming that it's a custom theme, will the error messages disappear if you use the default theme?

Also make sure that:

- You have cleaned your project and application server, and rebuilt the project
- You don't have two different versions of the Vaadin JAR in your WEB-INF/lib directory
- You haven't copied a theme directory from an older Vaadin JAR to your VAADIN/themes directory
- Your (assumed) custom theme isn't inheriting any old theme
- If you check the loaded css files in your browser (Firebug came in handy when I tried this), styles.css (or one of the styles.css') includes the following beginning part:

  .v-theme-version:after {
      content: "6_7_2";
  }
  .v-theme-version-6_7_2 {
      display: none;
  }

The only way I managed to produce this error was to inherit a custom theme from another Vaadin version's theme.

Update:
I checked your project and I think I know what's wrong. The servlet-mapping in web.xml should read /VAADIN/* instead of /vaadin/*. It should work without this change if you copy the themes from your vaadin.jar to VAADIN/themes in your project. Normally you should also copy the Vaadin widgetsets, but since you are using a custom widgetset, you don't have to do this.

Source: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.environment.html#section.web.web-xml

Comment: I do have a custom theme. I'm importing @import "../chameleon/styles.css"; The custom theme is almost empty, just adding an fav icon. I looked on my custom style.css file and it doesn't have 6_7_2 anywhere. I don't have multiple copies of Vaadin jar and my only jar for themes I have is vaadin-chameleon-theme-1.1.0.jar. My style.css file was generated by chamaleon theme app.

Comment: Is it named style.css or styles.css? It should be the latter. Your import looks fine. Did you check for 6_7_2 in your browser by looking at the HTML source?

Comment: Your custom styles.css shouldn't have the 6_7_2 part anywhere unless it's not inherited from another theme but created from the scratch. You can also try to remove vaadin-chameleon-theme-1.1.0.jar. I noticed a funny thing when I downloaded the same custom theme in 2 OSes; in Windows 7 I got my-chameleon.jar, README.txt and vaadin-chameleon-theme-1.1.0.jar but in Linux Mint I got only my-chameleon.jar. Try downloading Firebug and check if the CSS is loaded. You should see something like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9481707/custom_theme.png

Comment: Yes, I do see all the icos and stuff related to my theme on Firebug

Comment: Even if I don't set the theme to my custom one I have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you extracted the `VAADIN/themes` folder from `vaadin.jar` so that it is served statically? In that case, you need to update that directory with the contents from Vaadin 6.7.2.

Alternatively, have you created a folder under VAADIN/themes that has the same name as the Vaadin theme that you are using?

Comment: 1) I didn't extract the Vaadin/themes folder from the jar. 2) Yes I did. The custom theme is almost empty, just adding an fav icon. My style.css file was generated by chamaleon theme app.

Comment: What is the name of your theme folder and how does the import at the top of styles.css look like?

Comment: The name is xinco. The import is: @import "../chameleon/styles.css";